# Indenting the items in description environment

Tags: indentation, description

I have Q & A command that indents the start of the sentence, however using description environment breaks the indentation. How can I indent the description environment?

[image]

This is the source code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{question}
\setcounter{question}{0}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\Hrule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3mm}}

\makeatletter% since there's an at-sign (@) in the command name
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \parindent=0pt% don't indent paragraphs in the title block
  \centering
  {\Large \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}
  \HRule\par%
  \textit{\@author \hfill \@date}
  \par
}
\makeatother% resets the meaning of the at-sign (@)

\newcommand\Que[1]{%
   \leavevmode\par
   \stepcounter{question}
   \noindent
   Q\thequestion: \textit{#1}\par}

\newcommand\Ans[2][]{%
    \leavevmode\par\noindent
   {\leftskip10pt
    A: \textbf{#1} #2\par}}

\title{Title}
\author{A and B}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

%\section{MapReduce}
\Que{Q}
\Ans{
A
\begin{description}
\item[X] Y
\end{description}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean "how can I indent the `description` environment"?

Comment: @karlkoeller: Yes. Thanks, I updated my post.

Comment: How about using lists that you can nest, for example `\Que{question}{\A[abc]{xyz}}`? This would allow you to turn answers on/off for different versions of the Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `\leftskip` approach in the `\Ans` macro, I instead use a `\hspace` followed by a `\parbox` of reduced width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcounter{question}
\setcounter{question}{0}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\Hrule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3mm}}

\makeatletter% since there's an at-sign (@) in the command name
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \parindent=0pt% don't indent paragraphs in the title block
  \centering
  {\Large \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}
  \HRule\par%
  \textit{\@author \hfill \@date}
  \par
}
\makeatother% resets the meaning of the at-sign (@)

\newcommand\Que[1]{%
   \leavevmode\par
   \stepcounter{question}
   \noindent
   Q\thequestion: \textit{#1}\par}

\newcommand\Ans[2][]{%
    \leavevmode\par\noindent
   {\hspace*{10pt}\parbox{\linewidth-10pt}{
    A: \textbf{#1} #2\par}}}

\title{Title}
\author{A and B}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

%\section{MapReduce}
\Que{Q}
\Ans{
Answer that might be long enough to skip past the end of a line
Answer that might be long enough to skip past the end of a line
Answer that might be long enough to skip past the end of a line
\begin{description}
\item[X] Y
\end{description}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the idiomatic way: using lists

```
\newcommand\Ans[2][]{%
    \leavevmode\par\noindent
   {\begin{list}{}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{10pt}}%
    \item[]%
    A: %
    \textbf{#1} #2\par%
    \end{list}%
    }}
```

This way for every `\Ans` you start a list with a single item (with no label) and you can adjust every margin (see [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Customizing_manually) for example).

I should mention that unlike solutions using `parbox` here the contents of `\Ans` can span several pages and are not treated as an unbreakable block.

Comment: That's a good point about the `\parbox` limitation.